# Rounding up price with MySQL to the nearest 95p

Tags: mysql

I have prices on my site which I would like to round up.

rounded up to the nearest pound is simple but I'm getting suck rounding up the prices to the nearest 95p

for example the price of an item shows as 13.6800 (£13.68)
I want this to be rounded up to 13.9500 (£13.95)

how is this done? as I have 2130 product prices I need to update.

Comment: Please tell me you are not storing these numbers as floating point numbers

Comment: Does this have to be done with a MySQL function or could you do it with your back end language ie PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [control flow functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) but i think it's better to make this as a batch if you will execute same process for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  update prices set price = ROUND(price)+ 0.95
```

Should do the trick

Comment: @user3310348 - As to putting prices up you can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use ROUND as you do it for the nearest pound but with `0.05` shift:

```
ROUND(13.6800+0.05)-0.05
```